# greatest common divisor in ocl

Tags: greatest-common-divisor, ocl

How can I write an operation `gcd(x : Integer, y : Integer) : Integer` which returns the greatest common divisor of two positive integers (the largest integer which divides both of them exactly) in `ocl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution for this (certainly not effective, but it works):

```
let divs : Sequence(Integer) = if x < y then Sequence{1..y} else Sequence{1..x} endif
in divs->select(z | x.mod(z) = 0 and y.mod(z) = 0)->last()
```

What is simply done is that a sequence of each potentials candidates is generated, then, from this sequence, only the ones that divide `x` and `y` are selected and stored in a new sequence (which is ordered). Finally, the last number from this filtered sequence is your greatest common divisor.

Now in details:

1. we produce a sequence with `Sequence{a..b}`
2. this sequence is goes from `1` to the higher number between `x` and `y` (`if x < y then Sequence{1..y} else Sequence{1..x}`)
3. this sequence is stored in a immutable variable `divs` (`let divs : Sequence(Integer) = ... in ...`)
4. from `divs`, we select only the number `z` which is a divisor for `x` and `z` (`divs->select(z | x.mod(z) = 0 and y.mod(z) = 0)`
5. finally, we only take the last element from the new sequence (`select(...)->last()`)

If the `last()` function does not exist in your env (don't know why, but some OCL implementations bring their own functions), you can use:

```
->sortedBy(i | -i)->at(1)
```

instead of `last()`, which reverse the sequence and take the first element.

**EDIT>**

You can also reduce the expression this way:

```
let divs : Sequence(Integer) = Sequence{1..x.max(y)}
in divs->select(z | x.mod(z) = 0 and y.mod(z) = 0)->last()
```

or, by removing the use of `divs`

```
Sequence{1..x.max(y)}->select(z | x.mod(z) = 0 and y.mod(z) = 0)->last()
```

Comment: Is it support in standard OCL? what is the set to result or return?

Comment: I checked, `last()` is standard OCL (specification, p.170). It was the only point I was not sure about. Everything else is obviously standard. This expression does not work for you?

Comment: Bytheway, you can reduce the expression (see my edit), and everything is still standard OCL.